# setup() vs onMounted(),I need display a data when the page loads initialy...,where should i write the code for fetching the data form server (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In options api,its obvious where we write code for fetching the data from server in mounted method.
With composition api,i am confused as the setup method is the one that loads first before the onMounted hook.

Comment: well i think it's best to use created hook, or setup for composition api

Answer (score 10):

Check their docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram

If you are doing DOM related actions, you would want to do it in `onMounted()` hooks, because `setup()` doesn't have access to DOM yet.

So I would probably do it in `onMounted()` methods since I would probably store result from API to component data or may update DOM as a side-effect.

Comment: mounted hook is called late, user will notice it, i'm always using created hook, or setup, you don't really need dom if you just storing data. The sooner the better.

Comment: @Lk77 It's not better. The request is asynchronous any way. This will just make initial rendering slower by doing extra work too early.